# Regex to get expression in the second " "

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a line like this

> 20130215  Blah-blah-blah adflkjas aaa="12321343432" sdflkjsfdd bbb="A1-12345"

and I need to extract the value in between the second quotes. How do I do that?

This is in groovy.

Comment: Will it always be prefixed with `bbb=`? Also, don't forget to show us what you've tried.

Comment: What language/library/tool/etc.?

Comment: Second quotes will be always at the end of string?

Comment: I am not sure, this is log file from external program that I want to analyze and I don't know how it will behave, I have a shell script that has this logic (it gets value from between the second pair of quotes), so that's what I am trying to mimic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is `/^\d{8} .*=".*" .* .*="(.*)".*/`.

If you can guarantee that no `"` will appear on their own then you can use `/^\d{8} [^"]*="[^"]*" [^"]* [^"]*="([^"]*)"[^"]*/` instead.

If you can further constrain the .*s it might help, but as you've been very vague as far as allowable inputs I'm going to hope that this will suffice.  This assumes that you're always leading with an 8 digit date.

Groovy may need some additional escaping (perhaps on the double quotation marks).  You may also need to double escape with Groovy, it's been a while since I've played around there.  I believe your matcher will have the whole string and then your captured value.

If what you're after is the semantics of doing a regex capture in Groovy, I'd suggest http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+5+-+Capturing+regex+groups

There are some good examples there.

Answer (score 1):

This will extract the contents of the second pair of quotes:

```
 ($extracted = $line) =~ s/^[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*"([^"]*)"/$1/
```

start of line followed by zero or more not-quotes followed by a quote followed by zero or more not-quotes followed by a quote followed by zero or more not-quotes followed by a quote followed by (zero or more not-quotes) followed by a quote. $1 extracts the (group).

This is *not* the Groovy regex idiom (it's more Perl-ish), but the pattern should work in Groovy.